# Are there widespread filesystems which represent directories with structures optimized for fast lookup?

Tags: filesystems, directory

In "The Art of Unix Programming", on the topic of [The Terminfo Database](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch06s01.html) I read:

> If you look in the terminfo directory, you'll see subdirectories named
>   by single printable characters. Under each of these are the entries
>   for each terminal type that has a name beginning with that letter. The
>   goal of this organization was to avoid having to do a linear search of
>   a very large directory; **under more modern Unix file systems, which
>   represent directories with B-trees or other structures optimized for
>   fast lookup, the subdirectories won't be necessary.**

I wonder if there are widespread (i.e. production ready) filesystems with this quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several, e.g. ext4, Microsoft's NTFS,  Apple's HDF+, or the up and coming btrfs that use B-Trees. There are also HDF and Reiser4 which use B*-Trees, a more densely packed version of B-Tree.

Comment: ext4 actually uses a modified version of B-tree called [H-tree](http://ext2.sourceforge.net/2005-ols/paper-html/node3.html). This functionality is also available in ext3 through the [`dir_index`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htree) option.

Answer (score 1):

The ext3 file system also uses a hash ([discussion in debian-user](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/04/msg01264.html)). However, IMHO, this can have a bad consequence, at least for a traditional hard disk: this destroys some possible regularity / locality on disk. For instance, when files have been created one after the other in the directory, reading these files in the directory order can be very slow (see [some tests I've done](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/04/msg01310.html)). This is apparently why the [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) mail user agent does a sort by inode when reading a maildir folder ([commit f2eef427](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/commit/f2eef427ffde7ba2f668e7dcb241aff176dfa118), old changeset 3828).